# Can't install AnyEvent::DBI with Cpan on macOS High Sierra

Tags: perl, cpan, anyevent

there was a problem installing the AnyEvent::DBI for perl v5.18.2 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
As I understood, the AnyEvent::Fork dependency module is not installed, here's the information from CPAN

```
cpan[1]> install AnyEvent::Fork
Reading '/Users/dmitry/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 20 Feb 2018 15:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'AnyEvent::Fork'
Checksum for /Users/dmitry/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/dmitry/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for AnyEvent::Fork
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
cp Fork/Template.pm blib/lib/AnyEvent/Fork/Template.pm
cp Fork/Serve.pm blib/lib/AnyEvent/Fork/Serve.pm
cp Fork/Early.pm blib/lib/AnyEvent/Fork/Early.pm
cp Fork.pm blib/lib/AnyEvent/Fork.pm
Manifying 3 pod documents
  MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_load.t ...... ok
t/01_early.t ..... ok
t/02_template.t .. ok
t/03_new.t ....... ok
t/04_tofrom.t .... Failed 2/18 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_tofrom.t  (Wstat: 0 Tests: 18 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  16-17
Files=5, Tests=34,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.02 sys +  0.15 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.25 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/5 test programs. 2/34 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz           : make_test NO

cpan[2]> reports MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
Distribution: M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-Fork-1.31.tar.gz
Fetching 'http://www.cpantesters.org/show/AnyEvent-Fork.yaml'...DONE

Catching error: "CPAN::Exception::yaml_process_error=HASH(0x7fdfcd59c350)" at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/CPAN.pm line 392.
    CPAN::shell() called at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/App/Cpan.pm line 414
    App::Cpan::_process_options("App::Cpan") called at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/App/Cpan.pm line 511
    App::Cpan::run("App::Cpan") called at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 10

cpan[3]>
```

The most interesting on the previous version of macOS I installed this module.

Comment: This module's tests always [fail](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/A/AnyEvent-Fork.html#AnyEvent-Fork-1.31?grade=1&perlmat=2&patches=2&oncpan=2&distmat=2&perlver=ALL&osname=darwin&version=1.31) on OS/X. You could try approaching the author. He prefers being contacted by email (`schmorp@schmorp.de`) over using a bug tracker.